# Kafka failed to change state for partition from OnlinePartition to OnlinePartition

Tags: apache-kafka, runtime-error

I'm looking at logs for a problem we recently had with Kafka where we ended up with a full offset rewind.  It looks from the logs like we had two of 3 replicas drop out at the same moment, or at least that is what one of the nodes logs is saying.  Around that time, I see following log message repeated many times with different partition names:

```
ERROR [Controller id=0 epoch=71] Controller 0 epoch 71 failed to change state for partition PARTITION.NAME from OnlinePartition to 
OnlinePartition (state.change.logger) kafka.common.StateChangeFailedException: Failed to elect leader for partition PARTITION.NAME under strategy PreferredReplicaPartitionLeaderElectionStrategy
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$doElectLeaderForPartitions$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:328)
    at ...
```

What's odd about this is the part that says

> from OnlinePartition to OnlinePartition

When I search the Google for this, I come up with nothing really helpful.  The other thing is that all the stuff that does come up seems pretty old and refers to pre-1.0 versions of Kafka.  We are supposedly running 1.1.0.

Any ideas as to what why there would be an attempt to change partition to the state it appears to already be in?  I guess I can see how that could be considered a failure in that nothing would be changed but it seems nonsensical in general.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Kafka Controller Internals](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Controller+Internals) page this is a valid state transition when a new partition leader should be selected:

> Valid state transitions are:
>
> . . .
>
> **OnlinePartition, OfflinePartition -> OnlinePartition**
>
> 1. select new leader and isr for this partition and a set of replicas to receive the LeaderAndIsr request, and write leader and isr to ZK
>
>    ...
>
>    c. **PreferredReplicaPartitionLeaderSelector**: new leader = first assigned replica (if in isr); new isr = current isr; receiving replicas = assigned replicas
>
>    ...
> 2. send LeaderAndIsr request to every receiving
>      replica and UpdateMetadata request to every live broker

**EDIT**

regarding the reset offsets, could you check if [KAFKA-6189](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6189) is applicable in your case. If not, please share the configuration details of your cluster, topic and consumer group.

Comment: That's helpful thanks.  I'll check out the documentation you have provided.  Any idea what it means to fail when going from `OnlinePartition` -> `OnlinePartition`?

Comment: Do you have `unclean.leader.election.enabled` as false? Then the failure to elect a new leader probably means that the remaining replica(s) are not in ISR. Related  Controller logic --  https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/7a3dffb0ca1f7ff2bd838f42ca2f12b7a2fc3b0e/core/src/main/scala/kafka/controller/PartitionStateMachine.scala#L365

Comment: Great stuff.  Do you have any ideas or help on determining on what would cause a replica to not be in ISR?

Comment: There are too many to speculate, but common reasons usually involve node crashes or severed network connections. In my limited experience, I found broker logs reasonably detailed to identify the actual cause (just search for "Shrinking ISR from n1, n2, n3 ... to n1 ,..").

Comment: Seriously appreciate the help.  Ultimately I'm trying to figure out why this node decided to rewind the offset to the beginning i.e. about 400K messages back.  We got these messages, the other 2 nodes dropped out together at the same moment and then this one took over and then reset the offsets shortly thereafter.

Comment: I added one possible scenario why this could happen. If it doesn't fit, please share more details about your config and any useful things from the broker logs.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see any mention of offsets being out of range.  There are a few things that stand out like: "Error while creating ephemeral at ..., node already exists and owner '...' does not match current session '...'.  There's also a cycle of "Sending become-leader LeaderAndIsr request" followed by a series of "failed to complete preferred replica leader election."  This repeats a number of times.  I haven't only found a shrinking ISR message around the time this happened for a different cluster.  Looking farther back.

Comment: Found resignation log entries which is then followed by the ephemeral errors.  I think that's indicating some sort of issue rejoining the cluster based on the gist of things I'm seeing when I search on these.  Probably I should modify the question and add a lot of these details.

Comment: @jimmyjames having more details never hurt... Certainly, please add whatever you found to your question.